# Render content of ion-content to the centre of screen in IONIC 2/3

Tags: html, css, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I have created a   login page with username  and  password  inputs  followed  by button  and  hyperlink.
I  want  to place  entire  ion-content  to  centre of  screen  both  horizantally  and  vertically.

```css
ion-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  right: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}

// .div1 {
//     position: absolute;
//     background-color: green;
//     top: 0;
//     left: 0;
//     right: 0;
//     bottom: 0;
//     display: block;
//     width: 100%;
//     height: 100%; // contain: layout size style;
// }
// // .Absolute-Center {
// //   margin: auto;
// //   position: absolute;
// //   top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
// // }
// div {
//     position: absolute;
//     top: 0;
//     bottom: 0;
//     left: 0;
//     right: 0;
//     margin: auto;
//     width: 100%;
//     height: 100%;
//     background-color: transparent;
// }
```

```html
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content>


  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>User Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" type="text" style="background-color:transparent"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button padding (click)="homePage()" color=secondary ion-button full round>Login</button>
  <a (click)="registerPage()">New ? Register here</a>


</ion-content>
```

Can  you  suggest  some  other  ways  to  achieve it. the  output  should  be  very responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this style rule in the `app.scss` file:

```
.vertical-center {
    .fixed-content,
    .scroll-content {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

        ion-list {
            max-width: 300px; 
            width:100%; 
            margin: auto; 
            text-align: center;
        }
    }
}
```

And then wrap the items inside of an `ion-list` like this:

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>login</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding class="vertical-center">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item no-padding>
            <ion-label floating>User Name</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" type="text" style="background-color:transparent"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item no-padding>
            <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
            <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" type="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>

        <button padding (click)="homePage()" color=secondary ion-button full round>Login</button>

        <a (click)="registerPage()">New ? Register here</a>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Please take a look at **[this working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/e9p1IT?p=preview)**

Comment: its  aligning  everything  horizontally in center of screen.Flex-direction should  be  column type  in my  scenario

Comment: Oh, that's right, on my end I have everything inside of a form. I've updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: Its  aligning  to top of  screen.. Not  to  center.

Comment: Can  you  suggest  some link  where  i can  master flexbox implementation? Thanks  in advance

Comment: Sure... I use to learn from [css-tricks tutorials](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) when it comes to css-related things. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) could be also a good starting point :)

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your browser support requirements, you can use the CSS3 'transform' property, combined with absolute positioning, to place the div in the middle of the page.

First, use position:absolute to place the div 50% from the top and left of the page:

```
position:absolute;
top:50%;
left:50%;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bfdqL5um/1/
(red border is purely to illustrate the box)

This puts the top left corner of the div in the center of the page. You can then use transform/translate to move it back by 50% of it's height and width:

```
transform:translate(50%,50%);
```

The box is now perfectly centred.
https://jsfiddle.net/bfdqL5um/2/

This is supported in IE9+, and all other major browsers.

Note that with absolute positioning, you have to watch for the position of any parent elements. (i.e. if one of icon-contents parents is positioned, it may affect how the absolute positioning of this one is applied).

(First StackOverflow post so apologies if formatting or etiquette is poor!)

Comment: I just used -50% instead, but this is the first thing that was able to work for me

Comment: transform: translate(-50%,-50%); Otherwise it further pushes it down and right

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
<ion-grid  class="center-grid">
</ion-grid>
    ion-grid {
        &.center-grid {
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%) !important;
            display: block !important;
            /*width: 100%;*/
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to center content both vertically and horizontally. This might help you get started:

```css
ion-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>login</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>User Name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.username" type="text" style="background-color:transparent"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label floating>Password</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="user.password" type="password"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button padding (click)="homePage()" color=secondary ion-button full round>Login</button>
  <a (click)="registerPage()">New ? Register here</a>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: your  suggestion is  not  working,  Its  sticking  to top of  screen

Comment: Try giving the body `height: 100%`

Comment: .ion-content needs to be 100% height. In my answer this is achieved using `100vh`, which does work. I don't know why it's not working in your case. You can try adding `height: 100%` to `html` too.

Comment: Try adding `height: 100vh` to the `body`

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this:

```
#container {
  text-align: center;

  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML

```
<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
<div id="container"> 
PUT YOUR HERE CONTENT HERE 
</div>
</ion-content>
```

Tested in ionic/capacitor.